# Phonegap application not building correctly on http://build.phonegap.com

Tags: android, cordova

Lately I created a phonegap application with my windows 8.1 PRO with the phonegap v:6.4.2.

The application uses the deviceready event to start the camera for the user to scan a QR code. when I build my application using the phonegap build command the android version is built perfectly. but when I upload my www.zip folder to the build.phonegap.com platform the APK generated doesn't fire the deviceready event so the camera view never shows up.

my config file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.hidden" version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<name> app_title</name>
<description>
    app description
</description>
<author email="support@example.com" href="http://example.com">
    example Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="~2.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" source="npm" spec="~2.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~4.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="~1.5.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm" spec="~1.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="~2.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.1.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-120.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-152.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-144-xxhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxhdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-192-xxxhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxxhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="480" height="320" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="960" height="640" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024 " />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2008" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1496" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xxhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxhdpi" />
<!--<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-144-xxhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxhdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-192-xxxhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxxhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xxhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxhdpi" />-->

<!--<platform name="ios">
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-120.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-152.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="480" height="320" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="960" height="640" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024 " />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2008" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1496" />
</platform>
<platform name="wp8">
    <icon height="99" platform="wp8" src="www/res/icon/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" width="99" />
    <icon height="159" platform="wp8" src="www/res/icon/wp8/Background.png" width="159" />
    <splash height="1280" platform="wp8" src="www/res/screen/wp8/screen-portrait.jpg" width="768" />
</platform>
<platform name="windows">
    <icon height="150" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" />
    <icon height="30" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" />
    <icon height="50" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" />
    <splash height="300" platform="windows" src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" />
    <icon height="120" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="44" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" width="44" />
    <icon height="106" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" />
    <icon height="70" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" />
    <icon height="71" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" width="71" />
    <icon height="170" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" />
    <icon height="360" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" />
    <icon height="310" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
    <icon height="150" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
    <icon height="360" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" />
    <splash height="1920" platform="windows" src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" />
</platform>-->
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

I tried to include the config.xml file in my www folder like they recommand doing while uploading code.
The plugins list is working correcly when i build on my local machine.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: I don't know if you can include the info needed to help me answer this question. I suspect your missing a permission or config value expected by PhoneGap. Here is their page on using the camera, the first thing I notice is various configuration options, each needed for a different platform. This may be worth a look to help. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera

Comment: But why is it working on my local machine when  I do the phonegap build command

Comment: As I mentioned, without seeing a lot more detail, anyone who tries to answer this will likely be shooting in the dark. You need someone to sit down and go through the configs, code etc, and to also compare the final apks for any differences. This is beyond the scope of what I feel SO can help with.